# XSLT code to search for particular element in xml and add a new element next to the searched element

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I have a XML-document like this:

```
 <root>
      <child>
        <element1 name="name" type="string"></element1>
        <element1 name="id" type="string" ></element1>
         :
        <element2 source="s1" desc="d1"></element2>
         :
      </child>
    </root>
```

I have to add a new element (same name as `element1`) next to `<element1>` before the `<element2>`. How can I write an xslt so that my new element1 added once in file. I have tried to add new element with parent class but it adding in the last. I wanted it to added below the same group name as below

```
<root>
  <child>
    <element1 name="name" type="string"></element1>
    <element1 name="id" type="string"></element1>
     :
    **<element1 name="new"></element1>**
    <element2 source="s1" desc="d1"></element2>
     :
 </child>
</root>
```

but I still can't get it the way I want. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

To add a new element just before the first `element2`:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="element2[1]">
    <element1 name="new"/>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Of course, this assumes that at least one `element2` exists.

Comment: in my xml **element2** repeats more than twice. Like this                `<element2 source="s1" desc="d1"/>  <element2 source="path" desc="d2"/> <element3 name="textfield" type="string"/><element3 name="textfield" type="string"/><element3 name="textfield" type="string"/><element3 name="textfield" type="string"/><element2 source="s1" desc="d1"/><element2 source="path" desc="d2"/>                                                                                                <element2 source="path" desc="d2"/>

Comment: Not sure what your point is. If the above does not solve your problem, then edit your question, add your **new** example there **and** show the expected result of transforming it.

Comment: i totally agree with the answer you have suggested but i have a doubt if an XML contains more than one *element2* as i mentioned in previous comment ,because the new element will added for every <element2>. In that scenario how can i add a new node? i want it to be added only one time

Comment: @Ambika The suggested answer will insert the new element **only** before the **first** `element2`. So it doesn't matter how many of them you have - as long as you have at least one.